# Duplicate video object being created for video element in javascript. Controlling html5 video

Tags: javascript, html, video

I need to control the play and pause of video element in my website. The significant part of the html is given below.

```
   <object classid="clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B"
            codebase="http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab" width="800" height="515">
        <param name="pluginspage" value="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/" />
        <param name="src" value="http://lms.alefeducation.com/pluginfile.php/886/mod_lesson/page_contents/506/6N1.1%20Intro%20Video.mp4" />
        <param name="controller" value="true" />
        <param name="loop" value="false" />
        <param name="autoplay" value="false" />
        <param name="autostart" value="false" />
        <param name="scale" value="aspect" />
        <!--[if !IE]>-->
        <object data="http://lms.alefeducation.com/pluginfile.php/886/mod_lesson/page_contents/506/6N1.1%20Intro%20Video.mp4" type="video/mp4" width="800" height="515">
            <param name="src" value="http://lms.alefeducation.com/pluginfile.php/886/mod_lesson/page_contents/506/6N1.1%20Intro%20Video.mp4" />
            <param name="pluginurl" value="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/" />
            <param name="controller" value="true" />
            <param name="loop" value="false" />
            <param name="autoplay" value="false" />
            <param name="autostart" value="false" />
            <param name="scale" value="aspect" />
        <!--<![endif]-->
            <span class="mediaplugin mediaplugin_html5video">
<video  controls="true" width="800" height="500" preload="metadata" title="6N1.1 Intro Video.mp4">
    <source src="http://lms.alefeducation.com/pluginfile.php/886/mod_lesson/page_contents/506/6N1.1%20Intro%20Video.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
    <a class="mediafallbacklink" href="http://lms.alefeducation.com/pluginfile.php/886/mod_lesson/page_contents/506/6N1.1%20Intro%20Video.mp4">6N1.1%20Intro%20Video.mp4</a>
</video>

</span>
        <!--[if !IE]>-->
        </object>
        <!--<![endif]-->
    </object>
</span><br></p>
```

Now I am trying to control the video with the following code

```
var videos = document.querySelectorAll('video');
    for(i=0;i<videos.length;i++) {
        videos[i].id = 'video-'+i;
    }



  $(document).ready(function () {
    var interval = self.setInterval(function(){LoopForever()},1000);
    var video0 = document.getElementById('video-0');

      function LoopForever() {
          $.ajax({url:"http://localhost/StudentState.php",
          headers: {
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
                },
          success:function(data){
                var video0 = document.getElementById('video-0');

                if(video0.ended == false){
                      if(data >0){
                               video0.play();   
                        }  else{
                            video0.pause();
                        }
                }
            }

          })
      }
    });
```

But what happens that two video objects are created. And from the javascript code above, only the newly created object is being controlled, not the object being shown in the browser.

Do anyone have answer to this???

**Update**

The complete code goes here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<p><span class="mediaplugin mediaplugin_qt">
    <object classid="clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B"
            codebase="http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab" width="800" height="515">
        <param name="pluginspage" value="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/" />
        <param name="src" value="Area_of_irregular_shape.mp4" />
        <param name="controller" value="true" />
        <param name="loop" value="false" />
        <param name="autoplay" value="false" />
        <param name="autostart" value="false" />
        <param name="scale" value="aspect" />
        <!--[if !IE]>-->
        <object data="Area_of_irregular_shape.mp4" type="video/mp4" width="800" height="515">
            <param name="src" value="Area_of_irregular_shape.mp4" />
            <param name="pluginurl" value="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/" />
            <param name="controller" value="true" />
            <param name="loop" value="false" />
            <param name="autoplay" value="false" />
            <param name="autostart" value="false" />
            <param name="scale" value="aspect" />
        <!--<![endif]-->
            <span class="mediaplugin mediaplugin_html5video">
<video  controls="true" width="800" height="500" preload="metadata">
    <source src="Area_of_irregular_shape.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
</video>

</span>
        <!--[if !IE]>-->
        </object>
        <!--<![endif]-->
    </object>
</span><br></p>


<script>

        var videos = document.querySelectorAll('video');
        for(i=0;i<videos.length;i++) {
                videos[i].id = 'video-'+i;
        }



  $(document).ready(function () {
        var interval = self.setInterval(function(){LoopForever()},1000);
        var video0 = document.getElementById('video-0');

          function LoopForever() {
                  $.ajax({url:"http://localhost/StudentState.php",
                  headers: {
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
                },
                  success:function(data){
                                var video0 = document.getElementById('video-0');

                                if(video0.ended == false){
                                          if(data >0){
                                               video0.play();
                                                }  else{
                                                        video0.pause();
                                                }
                                }
                        }

                  })
          }
        });
</script>
</body>a
</html>
```

Now if I debug it in chrome, it is replicated.

Comment: What leads you to believe this is the case? A demo would be good in jsFiddle or similar.

Comment: Two videos were being played, though I have only one video element in the html file. Besides, If I paused the video seen on GUI in the browser, the other video continued to play. The second video could be controlled by the javascript code, but not the first which I could see in the browser. Btw, the two videos were of same content, that I confirmed from the audio which was being played.

Comment: You've got different versions of the video embedded into the page, right? You've got QT, MP4 (object), and MP4 (video). If you remove those <object> versions does it work?

Comment: Apart from code in <script> block, the <object> code has been automatically generated in moodle. So, I am not able to remove it. I need to control the video uploaded on moodle in some lesson. Once I upload a video file, moodle generates rest of code, the javascript code can be written and it is saved in database and added to page when the page is generated at runtime.

Comment: The inner object is being rendered into inner html document with video element embeded into it, for which I am not able to get control from javascript. The javascript gives control of the video element which is there in the video tag.

Comment: I'd recommend just sticking all that code into a .html file and opening it in a browser for testing. Then you can figure out what's going on without worrying about what's generated, or how to fix it. Just understanding what's happening will help you come up with ways around the problem.

Comment: @Whothehellisthat thanks for your help. It gave me insight to solve the problem. Though its a hack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood the problem and got a hack around it.

The inner object has a type video/mp4. So browser was rendering it as a video. And javascript code was just identifying it as an object. When trying to get video object through code, the script was giving reference to the code in video tag. So, two instances of the same video has been created. And through javascript, only the second video could be controlled.

Now here I got the hack. I won't say it is a standard solution. But its a way around the problem.

I got reference to the video element and appended it to the outer object. Now I removed the inner object.

So, the new video got rendered and now I have controls of the video through javascript.

Here goes the relevant code.

```
var objects = document.getElementsByTagName('object');

var video = objects[1].lastElementChild.firstChild.nextElementSibling;

var object0 = objects[0];

object0.appendChild(video);

object0.removeChild(object0.childNodes[17]);

var video = object0.lastChild;
```